# Calculation of angle between joined line segments

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I'm struggling with this. What is the best way to calculate the angles identified in the image, see link. Is there a general solution for all cases.

[Example problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYLoh.png)

Thanks once again

Comment: What information do you start with?

Comment: Thanks, I know the x,y of each point

Comment: In that case, I would just start creating right-triangles between each point with the next point, starting from the first point.  Then you can solve for the angles in those right-triangles which will let you do some simple geometry to get those other angles.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was a general solution to this. I am trying to code a solution in c++

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you are looking for a practical method.

Do you know that there exist a function ((which exist in Matlab but has an equivalent in many scientific packages) overcoming the difficulty of the "$\pi$ barrier" : it is $atan2$ (with two parameters)

Indeed, working with the formula $\cos \theta = \dfrac{xx'+yy'}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}$ is insufficient for dealing, as you need it, with angles in the $[0, 2 \pi)$ range. In fact, knowing $\cos \theta$, you cannot decide between $\theta$ and $2 \pi - \theta$. A remedy for the elimination of this ambiguity would be to compute as well $\sin \theta$.

But, in fact, $atan2(Y,X)$  ($Y$ first, $X$ second) does all the work !

For example $atan2(-1,-1)$ will give $5\pi/4$, $atan2(-\sqrt{3}/2,1/2)$ will give $5\pi/3$, etc.

---

Edit 1: Your problem will be easier to work on if you replace  exterior angles by interior angles. See figure below. Doing that, the "current  polygon", having the sum of its *interior* angles equal to $(k-1)\pi$ (think to this polygon as decomposed into $n-1$ triangles), considered as "closed" by $V_k=\sum_{i=1}^k V_i$, or more exactly by taking $-V_k$. In this way, you can follow the angles' modification by reference to this "invariant" $(k-1)\pi$.

Remark: the fact that the polygon is convex or not is unimportant (one deals with signed quantities, either signed angles, signed areas, etc.)

[image]

---

Edit 2: Here is a Matlab program that "solves" your problem, more or less in the spirit of Edit1 ; it uses complex numbers. I wish you can work with complex numbers in your environment ; otherwise, take real and imaginary parts when necessary...

Two keypoints : %(1) for the minus sign in order to reverse the next coming vector and %(2) for dealing with the good side (left hand side, when you imagine you follow the broken line).

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;
> X=[0,2,5,6.8,10,8,8.8];
> Y=[0,2,2,-2,5,-3,-4.2];
> plot(X,Y);
> Z=X+i*Y;
> D=diff(Z);
> for k=1:length(D)-1
>     an=angle(-D(k+1)/D(k))*180/pi;%(1)
>     if an<0
>         a(k)=abs(an);
>         else a(k)=360-an;%(2)
>     end
>     text(X(k+1),Y(k+1),[num2str(k),' ',num2str(a(k))]);hold on;
> end;
> a
> ```

Comment: yes I know about atan2

Comment: Please, have a look at the two "Edits" I have done to my first answer.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie, your effort is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you have three points $A=(x_A,y_A)$,$B=(x_B,y_B)$ and $C=(x_C,y_C)$ find the vectors: $\vec a=(x_A-x_B,y_A-y_B)^T=(a_x,a_y)^T$ and $\vec b=(x_C-x_B,y_C-y_B)^T=(b_x,b_y)^T$ ( this is a translation of the origin at $B$).

Find the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that:
$$
\cos \alpha=\frac{a_x}{|\vec a|} \quad \land \quad \sin \alpha=\frac{a_y}{|\vec a|}
$$
$$
\cos \beta=\frac{b_x}{|\vec b|} \quad \land \quad \sin \beta=\frac{b_y}{|\vec b|}
$$
these angles are uniquely determined and $0\le \alpha <360°$,$0\le \beta <360°$ and, if I well interpret your picture we have always $\alpha \le \beta$.

Now, using the knowledge of the signs os the components of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, you can separate the cases when the searched angle is $\theta= \alpha-\beta$ or $\theta'=360°-\theta$.

(Eventually you can solve analogously  also the case $\alpha \ge \beta$).

Comment: Thanks but this does not give a solution to the outer angles of the connected polylines, which is the problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: I see! And I've changed my answer. I hope that it works now :)

Comment: Thanks @Emiliio, I'll have to get out my maths books :)